# Django modelformset too slow on large numbers of data

Tags: django, django-forms

The model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    overview   = models.TextField(blank=True)
    portrait   = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('first_name', 'last_name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

The form/formset:

```
class PeopleNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = People
        fields = ('first_name','last_name') 
PeopleNameFormSet = modelformset_factory(People, form=PeopleNameForm)
```

The view:

```
def people(request):
    allnames=People.objects.all()
    fs = PeopleNameFormSet(queryset=allnames)
    return render_to_response('people.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now, the problem is when `fs = PeopleNameFormSet(queryset=allnames)` is executed, it takes about 5 minutes for 100K names on my macbook pro (4G memory), whilst `allnames=People.objects.all()` take no time.

What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: How much time does `list(People.objects.all())` take? Keep in mind that querysets are lazy in Django, i.e. your query is not executed until you do something with it, e.g. iterate over it/convert it to a list/construct a form out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Query sets in Django are lazy which means that the SQL statement will only be executed on the database when you access it or it is being evaluated in some way. So there isn't anything wrong with your code, you might need to consider indexing or some other optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, nothing is wrong  :)

Longer answer: The `.objects.all()` is lazy so afaik it gets activated only when you're (using it)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated].

Try to evaluate your `.all()` query and you'll see it takes some time too...